# sed to grep strings between two patterns

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a list of expressions in a file script.sh like

```
    1  name1  Pending    flag0
    2  name2  Completed  flag1
    3  name3  Completed  flag-
```

etc.,

I would like to grep specific status between "1" and "pending" (i.e name1).

I tried with this command

```
    var="1"

    cat script.sh |sed -n "s/^${var}\(.*\)Pending.*$/\1/gp"
```

this doesn't return anything.

Comment: That works for me. Are there any spaces before or after the line in your file?

Comment: Yes I found its not working when I use variable substitution

Comment: Hmm, even your example with a variable works for me.

Comment: is there any specific reason for my issue?

Comment: This can be done with grep alone, see my answer :)

Comment: The `/g` flag is only meaningful if you need to process multiple matches on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution needs only a minor modification:

```
var="1"

cat script.sh | sed -n "/^${var}.*Pending/{s/^${var}\(.*\)Pending.*$/\1/;p;}"
```

Comment: You should also lose the Useless Use of Cat. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: @tripleee: Yes.  Also, the second `^` and final `$` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

This in how you do it using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep): `grep -Po '(?<=1).*(?=Pending)' file`

```
$ cat file
    1  name1  Pending    flag0
    2  name2  Completed  flag1
    3  name3  Completed  flag-

$ grep -Po '(?<=1).*(?=Pending)' file
  name1
```

Here [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) is displaying only the matches that followed a `1` and precede the word `Pending`.

Note: this is using [positive lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
    sed -n 's/^1\(.*\)Pending.*$/\1/gp'
```

you got extra slash at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

How about an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution?

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i == "Pending") {print $(i-1)}}}' input_file
```